# Replace string with file content using npm / nodejs (not grunt / gulp based)

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I've been searching for a npm package in order to replace given strings with the content of files inside files. I can only find grunt or gulp based injectors / replace tools but nothing using simply nodejs...

I'd like to use this tool in a command line fashion, ideally. Anyone knows of a npm package that I have missed?

Comment: Do you want find & replace tool for multiple files? Like linux `sed`

Comment: @vmkcom I'd rather use it on a file to file basis. I found solutions using `sed` but I was looking for some npm package so that it could be used by others non-linux users

Comment: You could make your own module and share with the community as opposed to finding an existing one to share. `module.exports = coolToolBro` I'll keep my eyes peeled.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) may be suitable for your needs

> A simple utility to quickly replace text in one or more files.